# Django Rest Framework SimpleJWT, custom use case

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In DRF SimpleJWT, we need to set a value for when the Refresh Token and the access token would expire. So, the user must log in again after the refresh token expires. But when using Firebase Auth, the user does not need to log in repeatedly. Is there a way to emulate a similar behavior in Django Rest Framework, like in Firebase Authentication.